# how to set selectedindex of select2 dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-select2

I have an asp.net dropdown for which I added select2 and a clear button in my page. When I click on clear button I would like to be able to set to the option at zero index. Below is the code:

If I remove the select2 part, I'm able to clear the dropdown with "`ddlPatient.selectedIndex = 0;`"

```
$(document).ready(function() { debugger;   $("[id$=ddlPatients]").select2(); });

function btnClear_Click() {
    debugger;
    var ddlPatient = document.getElementById("<%=ddlPatients.ClientID %>");

    ddlPatient.selectedIndex = 0;
}

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPatients" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Clear" OnClientClick="btnClear_Click();return false;" />
```

Comment: $('#ddlPatients').select2().select2('val', '0');

Comment: Thanks for replying but that did not work

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I've spent a day on this same problem. Apparently, it's not possible to set Select2's index  from JavaScript nor JQuery (there is no documentation anywhere on their website concerning something this simple) - that is, set the selectedIndex via an ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPatients" runat="server" ClientID="”Echo”" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Then in script try...

```
 var $ddlPatients = $("select[name$=ddlPatients]");
 $('#ddlPatients').select2('val', '0');
```

or

$('#ddlPatients').select2().select2('val', '0');

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () { debugger; $("[id$=<%=ddlPatients.ClientID %>]").select2(); });
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () { debugger; $("[id$=ddlPatients]").select2(); });
```

You are using `ddlPatients.ClientID` in one place, but hard code the id somehwere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value of the underlying `<select>` element, you need to trigger its `change` event to cause the Select2 control to update itself to match.

```
document.getElementById("<%=ddlPatients.ClientID %>");

ddlPatient.selectedIndex = 0;

$(ddlPatient).change(); // Trigger the change event.
```

Or:

```
$("<%=ddlPatients.ClientID %>").prop('selectedIndex', 0).change();
```